# Why is this sprite not being displayed on the screen?

Tags: python, pygame

I made a class called `Player` that has an image called *player.img* that is not being displayed on the screen. When I run the code, it just displays a black screen with nothing on it. I'm trying to learn how to make classes so sorry if this is really messed up.

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *

#starts the program
pygame.init()

white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)
green = (0, 255, 0)
yellow = (255, 255, 153)

#creates a window of 800x600
setDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption('Menu')

img = pygame.image.load('C:\\Users\\Ben\\Documents\\sprite.png')

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        def __init__(self):
                pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
                self.img = pygame.image.load('C:\\Users\\Ben\\Documents\\sprite.png').convert()
                self.imgx = 10
                self.imgy = 10
                self.screen = pygame.display.get_surface()
        def draw(self):
                self.screen.blit(self.img)

        def load(self, filename):
                self.img = pygame.image.load('C:\\Users\\Ben\\Documents\\sprite.png').convert_alpha()


player = Player()              

def gameLoop():
    imgx = 10
    imgy = 10
    lead_x_change = 0
    lead_y_change = 0
    move_variable = 5

    while True:
        screen.blit(player.img, [player.imgx,player.imgy])

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            #print (event)
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

gameLoop()
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see two issues with your current code.

1. You never flip your display.  This is generally performed after all blitting is complete for a given frame.  For example your while loop would look like this:

   ```
   while True:
       screen.blit(player.img, [player.imgx,player.imgy])
       pygame.display.flip()

       for event in pygame.event.get():
           #print (event)
           if event.type == QUIT:
               pygame.quit()
               sys.exit()
   ```
2. Your gameLoop() function doesn't know what "screen" is.  You will need to specify it somewhere. For example, right before your while loop starts would be fine.

   ```
   screen = pygame.display.get_surface()
   while True:
       screen.blit....
   ```

You will definitely want to restructure some things.  If I have some time later I will add to this answer my recommendations for how to restructure.  But for now, these two adjustments should get your program running.